# Wrong Images are displayed from sqlite Database into ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I'm downloading some text and images from the server using AsyncTask. I'm storing the texts and images in sq-lite database. I'm storing in the form of byte array.

In post Execute method of AsyncTask I store the convert the images in byte array and store them in database using for loop.

Problem is when I display data in List View from database sometimes it displays the correct images but some times it displays wrong images.  I'm using a handler to delay the information into List View by 8 seconds. I've no idea why sometimes it shows the correct images and sometimes it shows wrong images.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I display the correct image every time. Moreover Can anyone help me how can I avoid the log cat message :

"Skipped XXX frames. The application is doing to much work in main thread."

I'm using fragments. As the application starts it will get data from server and which includes URL to Image. I'm using that URL to download images. Storing both the texts and images in database and showing it in List View in onPostExecute method.

Below are the codes I've used:

```
// convert from bitmap to byte array

    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
    new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

  }
```

In adapter class where I'm extending CursorAdapter class. I'm getting byte array from sq-lite database and converting it in image and display it to List View.

Code to convert from byte array to bitmap is below:

```
   private static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
   }
```

I'm setting it to list View item like this:

```
    byte [] image = cursor.getBlob(imageColumnIndex);

    if(image == null)
    {

    }else{
        Bitmap bitmap = getImage(image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Depends how you are saving images and retrieving them from database. From this code that is not possible to find out. `Skipped XXX frames. The application is doing to much work in main thread` - you need to move heavy tasks from main thread in background thread.

Comment: How can I move from main thread to background thread?

Comment: Usually problems like this happen when you’re loading images asynchronously and set the wrong image when your cell view is already reused for another data item. That often happens when you’re scrolling the listview fast.

Comment: I'm just loading images from database and sometimes they are right and sometimes images are duplicated or wrong.